# como habilitar o inhabilitar un input text dependiendo de otra variable?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

pregunta como haria para habilitar o inhabilitar usando el disable... el input dependiendo si analista.permisoCrear esta en true o false

```
<tr v-for="analista in detalleAnalista.data">
              <th scope="row">@{{ analista.nombre }}</th>
              <td>@{{ analista.cargo }}</td>
              <td><input type="checkbox" v-on:change="estados(analista.id,analista.idAnaProy,proyecto.id,proyecto.id_proyecto_division, $event)" v-model="analista.estatus" ></td>
              <td><input @keypress="formatoHoraAsignada"
                         @keyup="horasTotales" 
                         v-model="analista.horas_asignadas"

                         v-on:keyup="asigna(analista.id,analista.idAnaProy,proyecto.id,Asigproyecto.horas_contratadas, $event)"
                         class="form-control hora-asignada"
                         type="text"></td>
              <td>@{{ analista.suma }}</td>
              <td>
                <a v-bind:href="'/formCargarHoras/'+analista.idAnaProy" target="_self">
                <i class="fas fa-user-edit" v-if= "analista.permisoCrear"></i>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

Esta parte del js es cuando ya hice la busqueda y el self.detalleAnalista es el que tiene el permisoCrear el cual con el me gustaría habilitar o inhibilitar el input

```
if(response.status === 200 && response.data.response === true){

          self.detalleAnalista.data = response.data.analistas;
          self.detalleAsigproyecto.data = response.data.proyecto;

          for (var i = 0; i < self.detalleAnalista.data.length; i++) {
            self.horasComparar[i] = self.detalleAnalista.data[i].horas_asignadas;
            if (self.detalleAnalista.data[i].horas_asignadas === null) {
              self.horasComparar[i] = 0;
            }

          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la propiedad disable en el input, usando como varia de control lo que tenes en tu v-model...

una forma seria:

```
<input 
    :disabled="detalleAnalista.permisoCrear==1">
```

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvió